# Don't want grayed out Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chome extension. When you click on the extension icon, the `contextMenu` is accessible by a right-click and a left-click.

Actually, I don't have a `browserAction` in my `manifest.json`, so my problem is [my icon is grayed out](https://superuser.com/questions/994405/why-are-some-chrome-extensions-grayed-out-in-the-extension-toolbar). The solution is to add a `browserAction`. But if I add a `browserAction`, the left-click don't show the default menu, but shows nothing.

What I want is a colored icon and when I left-click that the default Chrome extension popup is opened.

Default Chrome Extension popup example:
[image]

My `manifest.json`

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Awesome app",
"version": "0.1",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
},
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "contextMenus"
],
"icons": {
    "16": "icons/se16.png",
    "32": "icons/se32.png",
    "158": "icons/se158.png"
   }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can't have the default menu AND a custom icon. Well, you can show/do something useful on click.

Comment: You know why? Or have an explication link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to have the default menu AND a colorful icon because the very presence of `"browser_action"` key means the extension wants to interact with the user and instructs the browser to either delegate icon click event to background page script in `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` listener or show a popup window if `"default_popup"` is declared in manifest or the popup was set programmatically via `chrome.browserAction.setPopup`.

The only way to "ignore" the click event in [browserAction API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) is to disable the icon via `chrome.browserAction.disable` which will gray it out thus defeating the initial goal.

Well, you can show/do something useful on click. The default menu isn't very useful, anyway.